# Querying Fomula cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Is it possible to run a query on formula populated cells? Every time I try I get a parse error. Is there a way to run a query on cells that are populated by a formula? or do I need to manually convert formula populated cells to values before running a query on them.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). A parse error indicates a problem with the _formula_ rather than the _data_. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Kindly share a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to run a `query()` on formula populated cells. Spreadsheet formulas work the same regardless of whether the parameter range contains static hand-entered values or formula results.

Comment: Every time I attempt to run a query on a formula populated cell, I get a parse error. the same exact query works fine on non formula populated cell.

Comment: Please show your formulas, and consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Answer (score 0):

standard QUERY formula syntax:

```
=QUERY(A:B; "select A,B where A is not null")
```

here you can find full documentation: **https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage**

also note that there is a specific order of sql parameters in the syntax